# Access Data "Advanced R Statistical Programming and Data Models"

Tags: r, file

might be a rather special question but im currently learning with the book "Advanced R Statistical Programming and Data Models" it has a chapter "Data Setup". However, i can't download any data in the way the book describes it. Has anyone here worked with the book and has an idea on how i can get my hands on the "04690-0001-Data.rda" file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [github repository for the book](https://github.com/Apress/advanced-r-statistical-programming-and-data-models) there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Apress/advanced-r-statistical-programming-and-data-models/issues/2) stating that the resource is 'lost' and that you have to download it from the source: https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/NACDA/studies/4690/versions/V9 (you can pick one of many formats but it looks like you need to create a login).

### Edit

So I was interested to find out what this book was about. It looks like a great resource. Turns out this file is the basis for many of the examples, and the "intro" to the book is basically taking the raw data and processing it for use in other examples.

I used my ORCiD to access and downloaded the raw data (delimited format) and loaded/processed it using:

```
library(data.table)
library(vroom)

df <- vroom(file = "~/Downloads/advanced-r-statistical-programming-and-data-models-master/ICPSR_04690/DS0001/04690-0001-Data.tsv")

options(
  width = 70,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  digits = 2)

acl <- as.data.table(df)
str(acl)
acl <- acl[, .(
  V1, V1801, V2101, V2064,
  V3007, V2623, V2636, V2640,
  V2000,
  V2200, V2201, V2202,
  V2613, V2614, V2616,
  V2618, V2681,
  V7007, V6623, V6636, V6640,
  V6201, V6202,
  V6613, V6614, V6616,
  V6618, V6681
)]

setnames(acl, names(acl), c(
  "ID", "Sex", "RaceEthnicity", "SESCategory",
  "Employment_W1", "BMI_W1", "Smoke_W1", "PhysActCat_W1",
  "AGE_W1",
  "SWL_W1", "InformalSI_W1", "FormalSI_W1",
  "SelfEsteem_W1", "Mastery_W1", "SelfEfficacy_W1",
  "CESD11_W1", "NChronic12_W1",
  "Employment_W2", "BMI_W2", "Smoke_W2", "PhysActCat_W2",
  "InformalSI_W2", "FormalSI_W2",
  "SelfEsteem_W2", "Mastery_W2", "SelfEfficacy_W2",
  "CESD11_W2", "NChronic12_W2"
           ))

acl[, ID := factor(ID)]
acl[, SESCategory := factor(SESCategory)]
acl[, SWL_W1 := SWL_W1 * -1]

saveRDS(acl, "advancedr_acl_data.RDS", compress = "xz")
```

That left me with a file called "advancedr_acl_data.RDS" which I then loaded for the GLM2.R section. The example code has some minor bugs that you will need to iron out but it looks like an excellent resource - thanks